Does gas have thermal radiation of continuous spectrum?
Related question: Thermal radiation of a nitrogen sphere
What kind of spectrum will a sphere of a heated gas have?
Will this spectrum be continuous or linear? Will it have continuous part?

Animho, too many questions in the same question

@basics I have removed extra questions which were confusing you, so please reopen

in principle, the spectrum at a single point in time is discrete since the gas is a discrete system. in practice, there are so many spectral lines that no physical spectrometer will be able to distinguish between them. also, their position is not fixed, so that any prolonged measurement (i.e. physical) will result in a true continuous spectrum.

@paulina what makes the discrete picture to change from instant to instant?
